# Python slicing list of tuples and converting values to integers - Confusion regarding why it's possible with numpy arrays but not list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I am trying to slice the first and last values from a list of list then convert these values to integers. I found a solution but I am confused why this solution works and am wondering if there is a simpler way as it seems rather inelegant.

The two ways I found to slice a single value from a list of a list are either to use list comprehension and then slice or convert to a numpy array then slice in two dimensions. Both of these take two steps.

**Question 1**: is there a single step solution to slice a single value out of a list of a list?
**Question 2**: Why is a mixed list (some values being numbers and some letters) not made up of integers and strings vs all tuples? Do numpy arrays or another approach allow mixed lists? Sorry if I am not using the correct terminology...

List of a list slicing - list comprehension method

```
#Say I have a list of a list with mixed numbers and letters.

>>>a=[('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S'), ('3', 'E', 'S'), ('4', 'T', 'S')]
#list comprehension slice 1D
>>>b=[list[0:1] for list in a]
>>> print(b):
[('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]

>>> start=(b[0:1])
>>> print(start):
[('1',)]
>>> end=b[len(b)-1:len(b)]
>>> print(end)
[('4',)]
```

List of a list slicing - numpy array method
    #Say I have a list of a list with mixed numbers and letters.

```
>>>a=[('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S'), ('3', 'E', 'S'), ('4', 'T', 'S')]
>>> b_array=numpy.array(a)
>>> print(b_array)
array([['1', 'T', ''],
       ['2', 'R', 'S'],
       ['3', 'E', 'S'],
       ['4', 'T', 'S']], dtype='<U1')

>>>start_array = b_array[0:1,0:1]
>>>print(start_array)
array([['1']], dtype='<U1')

>>>end_array = b_array[len(b_array)-1:len(b_array),0:1]
>>>print(end_array)
array([['4']], dtype='<U1')
```

Both approaches work but what confuses me is they behave differently if I call int() on them
List comprehension
If I either use list comprehension to try to turn all of `b` into integers

```
>>>b_int= [int(i) for i in b] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

or turn `start` or `end` into integers

```
>>>start=int(b[0:1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I get thrown similar errors. But the second says it is a list even though it's a single value in a 1x1 list.

Alternatively if I do the same for `start_array` it's fine

```
>>>start_array=int(b_array[0:1,0:1])
>>>print(start_array)
1
```

So in summary, I figured out a working solution but it feels clunky and I don't understand why this works in numpy arrays but not list of lists.

**Question 3**: Why can I convert values in numpy arrays into integers not list of lists?
**Question 4**: Is there a cleaner or easier way to do this in python?

Thanks

edit: So my misunderstanding was that I thought I was dealing with a list of lists. I was not, instead I was working with a list of tuples. I changed the title but not the body. My second problem was I was slice indexing and not scalar indexing. This resulted in not removing my elements from the list. For solutions I could either:

```
#List comprehension to reduce dimensionality
a=[('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S'), ('3', 'E', 'S'), ('4', 'T','S')]
b=[x[0] for x in a]
start=int(b[0])
end=int(b[-1])

#Directly index with a scalar
start=int(b[0][0])
end=int(b[-1][0])
```

I will directly index with a scalar as it's simpler. Though if I wanted to index several numbers list comprehension would be more useful.

Comment: you can use `b=[int(tup[0]) for tup in a]` to get first value of each tuple from a list of tuples and convert to `int`. if you want to access the first and last values use `b[0]` and `b[-1]`. your original list is a list of tuples not a list of lists. refer [here] for details about list indexing(https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/indexing.html)

Comment: 1) you don't have a lit of lists, you have a list of tuples 2) `numpy` being better at slicing in multiple dimensions is one of the key selling points of `numpy` and why we even have things like string and object `ndarray`s (otherwise `numpy` is designed for calculations) 3) fancy indexing makes extracting first and last elements easier: `start = b[[0]], end = b[[-1]]`

Comment: oh I see. I misunderstood what a tuple was... So thats the significance of the parentheses inside the brackets format. My bad- thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first and last number to be converted to integer, you can simply do this:

```
a = [('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S'), ('3', 'E', 'S'), ('4', 'T', 'S')]

firstNum = int(a[0][0])
lastNum = int(a[-1][0])

print(firstNum)
print(lastNum)
```

There is no need for slicing or other complicated logic.
And you are getting error because you cannot convert a tuple into integer, select the item inside tuple and then convert it

Comment: Thanks. This is far simpler and cleaner then what I was doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing with slices, which returns a list (or tuple).  Indexing with a number (scalar) takes an element out of the list (or tuple):

```
In [8]: a=[('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S'), ('3', 'E', 'S'), ('4', 'T', 'S')]                  
In [9]: b=[x[0] for x in a]                                                                    
In [10]: b                                                                                     
Out[10]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
In [11]: b[0]                                                                                  
Out[11]: '1'
In [12]: int(b[0])                                                                             
Out[12]: 1
In [13]: b[-1]                                                                                 
Out[13]: '4'    # int(b[-1]) works
```

Similarly with an array.  Slice index retains the dimension, scalar index reduces the dimension(s):

```
In [14]: arr = np.array(a)                                                                     
In [15]: arr                                                                                   
Out[15]: 
array([['1', 'T', ''],
       ['2', 'R', 'S'],
       ['3', 'E', 'S'],
       ['4', 'T', 'S']], dtype='<U1')
In [16]: arr[0,:]                                                                              
Out[16]: array(['1', 'T', ''], dtype='<U1')
In [17]: arr[:,0]                                                                              
Out[17]: array(['1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='<U1')
```

Note the `arr` dtype; we can change that to `int`:

```
In [18]: arr[:,0].astype(int)                                                                  
Out[18]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In general you don't want to use `int(b_array[0:1,0:1])`.  It works for one number, but not several:

```
In [19]: int(arr[:,0])                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-9c2041fff718> in <module>
----> 1 int(arr[:,0])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The `list` indexing is the Python original.  `numpy` has extended this indexing.  `numpy` extensions have not been back-ported to `list`.

---

Something you may have missed is that iterating on a list takes items out of the list.

```
In [26]: [x for x in a[:2]]                                                                    
Out[26]: [('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S')]
```

is equivalent to indexing with a scalar:

```
In [27]: [a[i] for i in range(2)]                                                              
Out[27]: [('1', 'T', ''), ('2', 'R', 'S')]
```

Indexing with slice 'wraps' each `x` in a list:

```
In [28]: [a[i:i+1] for i in range(2)]                                                          
Out[28]: [[('1', 'T', '')], [('2', 'R', 'S')]]
```

In `b=[list[0:1] for list in a]`, `list` is one of the tuples in `a`.  It is not a `slice` of `a`.

```
In [29]: a[0][0:1]         # slice of a tuple from a list                                                                             
Out[29]: ('1',)
In [30]: a[0:1][0:1]       # slice of a slice                                      
Out[30]: [('1', 'T', '')]
In [31]: a[0][0]           # element of a tuple from the list                                                  
Out[31]: '1'
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the thorough description. That's what I was looking for! It seems I really wasn't understanding what I was doing!